# Anyone having Zoom audio issues?

Tags: sound, zoom-meeting

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and the Zoom deb package. Sometimes when I join a Zoom conference, I cannot hear anyone. I have to quit and call back and then the audio works.  Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Are you connected to your router via ethernet or wi-fi?  If wi-fi, have you prioritized your device in the router?  Signal strength and noisy neighbors on the same channel may be found with sudo iwlist scan.